# Typedefs for available/unavailable types

Tags: c, typedef, c99

I have a C module `foo.c` which defines a function

```
json_t* foo_to_json(foo_t*);
```

The user of this code may or may not have the Jannson library available, I check that with autoconf, feed the value in by `config.h` and include the Jannson header conditionally.

```
#ifdef HAVE_JANNSON_H
#include <jannson.h>
#endif
```

I use this function in a few places, and rather than `#ifdef` around every call, I find it convenient to have a "fail version" in place

```
#ifdef HAVE_JANNSON_H

json_t* foo_to_json(foo_t *foo)
{
  <create and return a json_t>
}

#else 

json_t* foo_to_json(foo_t *foo)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "no JSON support\n");
  return NULL;
}

#endif
```

Problem: `json_t` is not defined if `jannson.h` is not included.  I know that in that header, it is defined as

```
typedef struct json_t { <details> } json_t;
```

and I find that including the *partial*

```
typedef struct json_t json_t;
```

in my code [edit: in my code's header] allows it to compile with gcc 10 -Wall -Wextra, with or without the  `jannson.h` header.  I know that you shouldn't "double typedef" prior to C11, and I'd like to support earlier C versions.  Is there a way?

Possible methods:

- use `struct json_t*` everywhere instead of the typedefed `json_t`, that does seem to work, but is a bit ugly ...
- use `void*` everywhere, rely on casting to `json_t*`, again, seems to work, but even uglier.

Is there an elegant solution?

Edit: In response to comments, the partial typedef that I'm using is in the header which exports `foo_to_json` and is installed, so making that typedef conditional on `HAVE_JANNSON_H` would mean exporting/installing that too, and I'd like to avoid that.  I have considered making a `foo-config.h.in` from which `configure` generates the partial conditionally (but which can be installed without `config.h`).

Comment: put the partial in the #else of that include test?

Comment: Besides the option of putting the `typedef` in the `#else` portion where the alternative function definition is made, you could also change the conditional inclusion of the header to `#ifdef HAVE_JANNSON_H` / `#include <jannson.h>` / `#else` / `typedef struct json_t json_t` / `#endif`. Did you miss these simple solutions, or is there some reason they are unsuitable?

Comment: IMO you should not be writing an error message to `stderr` from a library.  You're *assuming* how *everyone* who might use your library uses the standard streams.  Also, note that [all `*_t` identifiers are reserved under POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_02).

Comment: @AndrewHenle: `json_t` is not OP’s type.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use the "#ifdef HAVE_JANNSON_H" inside "jannson.h" in order to define things according to what is available? Everyone would include "jannson.h" unconditionally, and "jannson.h" would define things according to what is available or not.

Comment: @virolino: OP is not the publisher of `jannson.h` and does not have control over it. It is published by a third party and may or may not be present on the system of a client of OP.

Comment: oh, that's not good... (I did not get piece of info before)